# How are ratios shown in trading view computed for XABCD harmonic pattern? Unable to match one of the ratios

Tags: trading

I am breaking my head since last few days on this issue related to harmonics, if anyone can help I would be supergrateful!!

**Question**

In XABCD pattern, when i plot it in tradingview, I cannot understand how is XAD ratio is computed by trading view (encircled by red in picture below). formulation that i do by hand to compute it is CD/XA but it doesn't match what trading view shows. neither does AD/XA. other ratios match when i compute by hand.

**What I have tried**

- I tried all permutations for values of X,A,B,C,D but am just not able
  to match 4th ratio of XAD. Literally wrote code to do that for all 45 combinations possible.
- Scavenged the internet, but its full of how to leverage harmonics to make trades but no example computation, none for platform I am using: Trading View.

[image]

Image context

- 3 ratios match by hand, but unable to understand formulation for 4th
  one as highlighted in picture
- Data I used to create this sample image is (X, A, B, C, D) = (0.1582, 0.0995, 0.1345, 0.0747, 0.1045)

Comment: I don't know tradingview and don't know what xabcd is. However, it's usually give to not be able to replicate. If you could, you can just do the stuff yourself in the first place. Either you trust platforms or you don't. Are you close? If so, it's usually just some specific details that really don't matter much. E.g. I have seen [this Bloomberg cmm](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/74229/70573) time decayed z-score replication. While interesting, there isn't much to gain by knowing exact details. Most professional traders would never be able to replicate the pricing tools of their firms.

Comment: "Harmonic pattern" sounds like it might be quant theory; the quants have their own stack so you might try asking there. Personally this strikes me as numerology rather than statistics; the mere fact that you can compute something from past data points does not give it predictive value for future results. If there is any signal there, I strongly suspect it's buried in the noise floor -- otherwise the pros, who can and do throw huge amounts of computer time at this, would be more successful than they are.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because quantitative investing is akin to monkeys throwing darts.